# Classic asp filling value on drop down box but won't display the text

Tags: html, asp-classic

as above, when I run my code it pulls from the db and when I examine it using devtools in the web browser it has populated all the value fields on the drop down correctly. Although yet I can't for the life of me figure out why it won't display the text. My code is below + a SS. (The drop down highlighted doesn't display the text). This is the first thing I have ever done in asp so it's hopefully something simple I'm missing, Thanks in advance.

```
Set newconn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
newconn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=123;DATABASE=123[![enter image description here][1]][1];UID=123;PASSWORD=123"
newconn.Open

Set nameid=newconn.execute("select * from v_emp_list_with_mngr order by knownas" )

<TR>
    <TD>Name of Employee</TD>
        <TD>
            <select style="width:155px" size="1" name="knownas"><option value="">-- Please Choose --</option>
                <%Do While NOT nameid.EOF%>
                    <option value="<%response.write nameid.fields("knownas")%>"><%response.write nameid.fields("knownas")%></option>
                <%
                nameid.movenext 
                Loop %>
            </select>
        </TD>
  </TR>
```

Comment: classic ASP or ASP.NET? Your tag and title contradict each other. It _looks_ like classic ASP, but please clarify and re-tag. Your connection string also looks like some StackOverflow markup got mixed up in it.

Answer (score 1):

Set nameid=newconn.execute("select * from v_emp_list_with_mngr order by knownas" )

work one result
example nameid(0) call first recort
dont work code execute methot

```
set kisiler = server.createobject("adodb.recordset")
SQL="select * from v_emp_list_with_mngr order by knownas"
kisiler.open SQL,newconn,1,3


    <%Do While NOT kisiler.EOF%>
    <option value="<%=kisiler("knownas")%>"><%=kisiler("knownas")%></option>
   <%
    kisiler.movenext 
    Loop %>
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the data type of the column?

We've had issues where any type of TEXT field (ie: not char or varchar) can be used once from the Record Set, and then NEVER AGAIN. O_O (admittedly, this is with a MySQL connector.)

The solution was to put it straight into a variable, and use that.

Try writing out the DB content without the HTML. That is, construct a loop, and just output it to screen?

`Value: <%=nameid.fields("knownas")%>`

`Text: <%=nameid.fields("knownas")%>`

Then try putting it into a variable first, and write it out.